# Redirect to other page if fatal error comes

Tags: php, fatal-error

Is there any way i can redirect my visitors to other url if i got fatal error? or any way by which i can ignore that fatal error so that it will solve problem. fatal error show to some user based on less than 30 facebook friends.  Error is this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 100: null does not resolve to a valid user ID thrown in /home/scorpio/public_html/domain.com/src/base_facebook.php on line 1024
```

Comment: If you're throwing an exception why don't you catch it? Refer to the docs at [PHP Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: can we see what you have currently? what is causing the exception to go uncaught? maybe we could fix that part of the code with you

Comment: all functions are working proper but finding any way which can ignore this error or if detect so redirect to other page

Answer (score 0):

catch this exception! [Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)